# Django app structutre and circular reference

Tags: django, model, circular-reference

I'm trying to keep my project well organized, so I try to keep it splitted to apps.
Assume a blog app with a `BlogPost` model.
Now I add to that a `Tag` app, which has a Tag model with foreign key to Post. 
Now if I want to write a method `get_tags()`, in the `Blog` class, that would be circular reference.
So is that a bad design? Maybe I should not write such  method on the blog, or such related models should simply be in the same app?
I'm Simply trying to learn how to organize my (big) project. I've read a lot about django app concept, stil haven't found a right way

Comment: Please provide a small sample of your models.

Comment: I don't know if its bad design, but its not needed since django already provides reverse key lookups

Answer (score 1):

The point here is that Django automatically creates reverse lookup when you create a ForeignKey or ManytoManyField. Assuming your models are as follows:

**BlogPost Model**

```
from django.db import models

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(_('body'), )
    publish = models.DateTimeField(_('publish'), default=datetime.datetime.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
```

**Tag Model**

```
from django.db import models    
from Blog.models import BlogPost

class Tag(models.Model):
    Post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost,related_name="tags")
```

Now, assuming you are generating the Tags of a post in a view, you can basically get all the tags of a post by just calling `blogpost.tags_set` where **blogpost** is a model instance of `BlogPost`.

Comment: Ans what if I want only specific tags let's say from a specific date, or the latest? Should I write that in a method.   The point is about design - if it is correct to split such models into apps. I commonly see they should after some reading

Comment: @user3599803 that would just be `blogpost.tags_set.filter(created=date)` or something of that sort

Comment: @user3599803 And yeah it's perfectly fine to split your models into different apps. It would actually help in the long run to account for things as they are modularized in different apps and easy to pinpoint.